# Update Facebook SDK issue

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, facebook-sdk-4.0

I use Facebook SDK login feature. In console written

> Your Facebook SDK is out of date. We recommend upgrading to the latest Version 4.37.0, to ensure your app's performance is not affected and to take advantage of our newest features!

I updated SDK pods to 4.44.1, but this warning still there. Anybody can help me, what's wrong?
P.S. I've tried to delete pods and manually installed SDK from Facebook developer site, but it did not help

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce the same issue on `FBSDKLoginKit` versions 4.38.0 to 4.44.1.

It does not affect the behavior of the SDK, you can safely ignore this log.
As discussed on [Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/495) :

> Facebook SDK for iOS started to send an improper User-Agent header
>   using a wrong format FBiOSSDK.5.x.x instead of a traditional one
>   FBiOSSDK/5.x.x with a slash; I've discovered this by capturing the log
>   message and following the stack trace up to the request data.
>
> This needs to be fixed by the Facebook iOS SDK team.
>
> Edit: as the User-agent composing point in the SDK looks untouched for
>   the last 4 years, I suspect it's some kind of API change which broke
>   support for the non-standard User agent format SDK uses an only
>   accepts User-agents with a / slash. Thus an API error. Reported and
>   waiting for further steps from FB devs.
>
> Edit 2: submitted for fixing; should flawlessly resolve this issue
>   with some future Facebook API fix.

Answer (score 0):

re "Your Facebook SDK is out of date. We recommend upgrading to the latest Version 4.37.0, to ensure your app's performance is not affected and to take advantage of our newest features!"
Well I get the same log in my swift app after updating Facebook SDK via pods
April 13, 2019.

I recommend you add the two lines of swift code in viewDidLoad to see what version you have.

---

```
    let fbSDKVersion = FBSDKSettings.sdkVersion()
    print ("viewDidLoad- FBSDKVersion: \(fbSDKVersion ?? "0.0")")
```

---

My console log shows FBSDKVersion: 4.44.1.
 which makes the Version 4.37.0 message suspicious.